# spring-hateoas, How to set place holder value when building hypermedia link using onMethod

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I am doing a restful application.I have been trying to build a hypermedia link for a method which has pathvariable `teacherId` as shown in my code below. I used `methodOn` to build a link for `getAllToturialByTeacher` method, for example, `http://localhost:8080/springexample/teachers/2/toturials`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( value = "/teachers", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
public class ToturialController {

    ......  

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{teacherId}/toturials",method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Toturial>>> getAllToturialByTeacher(int teacherId){

        ......

        resource.add(linkTo(ToturialController.class)
                .slash(linkTo(methodOn(ToturialController.class).getAllToturialByTeacher(teacherId)))               
                .withRel("subjectsByTeacher"));
        ....
        return new ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Toturial>>>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And I got exception error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'teacherId'
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$MapTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$FullPathComponent.expand(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand(UriComponentsBuilder.java:398)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.java:139)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:138)
```

I could not set the value for placeholder `{teacherId}`. Could anyone give me a solution or best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller the teacherId is not annotated as `@PathVariable`.

Also your link creation looks broken - try this:

```
resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(ToturialController.class).getAllToturialByTeacher(teacherId)).withRel("subjectsByTeacher"))
```

Comment: I think this is the same as mine except for number of lines which I broke into 3 lines for more `readability`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No it is not - you have this `.slash()` method first - that is useless. Also the main point is that you do not annotate your controller method argument with `@PathVariable` - that is your main problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried your code but did not work. Thanks

Comment: What did not work? Did the @PathVariable solve your issue?